# How to implement payment gateway in Android kotlin and unlock the contact after payment successfull

Tags: android, kotlin, payment, unlock

I have got my first project on fiverr and it's 80% completed

The only thing left is implement payment gateway and when payment is done unlock the address and contact of person who has posted the ad

Basically its a room rental app where specific persons post ads and user can get the contact number of those persons posting ad

I have not previously implemented payment gateway so I don't know about how it works and how I will be testing it that after payments it's showing contact or not

Will I have to make actual payments to test the app?

Payments need to be done from user to directly client account

Comment: If you want to use payment gateway then stripe can be used. For testing purpose you have to setup sandbox environment which will not cost you any money while testing.https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-integration?terminal-sdk-platform=android

Comment: Thanks I will checkthis out one thing more is this is free of cost becoz  this is a production level app

Comment: No, this is not free. You can read the stripe doc for more information.

Comment: can I implement it for free and later the client buy its services... I just don't want to pay as developer

Comment: You can read through the docs of stripe for this thing.You will get a better idea after reading the docs.as far as I know it will ask you to create an create an account in stripe and you can follow steps after that